# Swift - UIView origin returning 0 when set at 140

Tags: swift

let form = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 140.0, view.bounds.width, 196))

print(form.bounds)

Prints: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 196.0)

Why is the Y origin returning 0.0?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are printing `form.bounds` instead of `form.frame`

The bounds rectangle is always relative to a view's own coordinate space, whereas the frame rectangle is relative to its superview's coordinate space. And a view's origin is always (0,0) relative to itself.